# Is it possible to have volumetric light when sun isn't being rendered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl

I'm working on a Vlumetric Light effect from a tutorial :

[Image of volumetric light in my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Zg6.png)

But the problem is that when the sun isn't getting rendered the volumetric lights doesn't work :

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OVjV.png)

I couldn't find anything by searching.

I'm thinking of a way to render sun with some offsets or something like that ...

I'm a begginer to hlsl programming.

You can find all code in this tutorial site : https://www.kodeco.com/22027819-volumetric-light-scattering-as-a-custom-renderer-feature-in-urp

Answer (score 0):

The c# script sets the "_Center" parameter of Radial blur material. So, set the Sun position with a custom objects position, but for the effect to work visually, you need a bright background at that Position.

```
Vector3 sunDirectionWorldSpace = RenderSettings.sun.transform.forward;
Vector3 sunPositionWorldSpace = cameraPositionWorldSpace + sunDirectionWorldSpace;

Vector3 sunPositionViewportSpace = 
camera.WorldToViewportPoint(sunPositionWorldSpace);
```

Above lines can be changed to a game object say MyEmissivePlane a white Emissive plane acting like sun

```
Vector3 MyEmissivePlaneDirectionWorldSpace = MyEmissivePlane.transform.forward;
Vector3 MyEmissivePlanePositionWorldSpace = cameraPositionWorldSpace + MyEmissivePlaneWorldSpace;
Vector3 MyEmissivePlanePositionViewportSpace = 
camera.WorldToViewportPoint(MyEmissivePlaneWorldSpace);
```

And set material parameter "_Center"

```
radialBlurMaterial.SetVector("_Center", new Vector4(
MyEmissivePlaneViewportSpace.x, MyEmissivePlaneViewportSpace.y, 0, 0));
```

Now, MyEmissivePlane will act like sun for this effect it has to be bright BTW.
Hope this helps

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer ! I did what you said but still hv the issue :( Do you have any other fixes for this ?

Comment: What happened any screenshot?

Comment: when I look at the sun : https://imgur.com/a/uSU9tFB and when I dont : https://imgur.com/a/4h0mhmX and I did changed the code as you said :(

Comment: the effect flips when I look oposite direction :https://imgur.com/a/ApECUAn you see the little darkness around objects

Comment: what about I get a panoramic view from another camera and add the effect to final render compared to players camera FOV ?

Comment: This way sun is always rendered

Comment: but I dont know the code :( can you help me and then I mark your answer

Comment: This tutorial is basically a post processing affect with more control because it's happening a custom render pipeline faking the look whole panorama view would be overkill. It's too much to talk about here maybe use unity reddit